# How to derive the functional for a given differential equation using the variational expression?

Tags: finite-element

[image: Excerpt from book - FEM by using Matlab by Kwon et.al.]

In the attached image, I want to understand **how to arrive at the equation 2.5.1**, i.e. the variational expression. The problem is defined as best as it could and the further derivation follows smoothly.

The complete derivation is as shown in the image below:

[image: Complete Derivation]

I am interested in how the eq 2.1.1 leads to eq 2.5.1 ... or rather how does the variational operator (del) work?

Comment: This doesn't affect the general question, but (2.5.1) is *not* the variational form of (2.1.1), which contains a Dirichlet (or essential) boundary condition.

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match the question: Are you asking how to derive the variational form of a partial differential equation, or are you actually interested in finding a functional whose minimizer satisfies the variational form of the equation?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a reference to whatever book or paper this image came from so that we could help you establish the context. I think there must be more information available prior to this point in the discussion.

Comment: (2.5.1) is also not a correct statement of the Neumann boundary term.  A term like that (with opposite sign) should arise from integration by parts, but it doesn't appear from thin air when you integrate against a test function.  This document appears to be quite confused; you may want to try a different resource.

Comment: @BillBarth: This image is from Finite Element Method using Matlab - KwonBang - CRC Press.

Comment: @ChristianClason: Yes, the title is a little misleading, though not intentionally so. I want to understand the first step in th derivation of the functional. The first step being the variational expression shown, i.e. 2.5.1

Comment: Work backwards. The derivation almost never proceeds in the direction this book goes in. You almost always work from 2.5.4, compute a Frechet or Gateaux derivative, set it equal to zero, integrate by parts, and thus (more or less) derive the Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional. This books seems to have it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the variational problem

$$I[u]=\int_a^b \Bigl(\tfrac12 u_x(x)^2+V(x,u(x))\Bigr)\,dx$$

leads to the functional derivative

$$δ I[u,δu]=\int_a^b \Bigl(u_x(x)δu_x(x)+V_u(x,u(x))δu(x)\Bigr)\,dx$$

and after partial integration

$$δ I[u,δu]=[u_x(x)δu(x)]_a^b+\int_a^b \Bigl(-u_{xx}(x)+V_u(x,u(x))\Bigr)δu(x)\,dx$$

The boundary conditions lead to $δu(a)=0=δu(b)$, identifying the terms in $u_{xx}=V_u(x,u)$ with the given equation to $V_u=u-x$, thus $V(x,u)=\tfrac12u^2-xu$.

Comment: And how to we get I[u]? Is it the standard integration equal to the energy ?

Comment: and mostly .. as the edited question shows .. i want to understand .. how to get the δI...which then results to I and not from I.

Comment: In going backward. From $u_{xx}=V_u(x,u)$ you identify $V_u(x,u)$ in your equation, integrate to get $V$ (up to a function in $x$) and insert into the general form for $I$.